# For a structure variable,why is the initializer {21,19,3.6} same as {{21,19},3.6},but not vice-versa?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, curly-braces, braces

In the following example,I've illustrated this using two structures `test1` and `test2`.The first has two elements-an integer array sized two,and a float element.The second structure has 3 elements,2 integers and one float.

I initialize two structure variables **s1** and **s2** for **test1** as:

```
s1={{23,52},2.5},s2={21,19,3.6};
```

Both work fine even though for **s2** I have taken out the braces that enclose the array elements.It works fine without warning and output is correct.But when I initialize 2 variables for **test2** as follows:

```
 v1={{23,52},2.5},v2={21,19,3.6};
```

I get incorrect output when I try to print out values of **v1** and these are the warnings that I had got upon compilation:

```
warning: braces around scalar initializer|
warning: (near initialization for 'v1.list1')|
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer|
warning: (near initialization for 'v1.list1')|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 4 warnings ===|
```

Based on this premise,please clear the following doubt that arise:

**Question:** If using `v1={{23,52},2.5}` instead of `v1={23,52,2.5}` confuses the compiler about whether the first 2 numbers are distinct integer elements of the structure or part of an integer array element of the structure,then why doesn't using `s2={21,19,3.6}` instead of `s2={{21,19},3.6}` confuse the compiler into thinking that the structure varialbe **s2** has **3** elements (2 integer elements and one float),instead of **2** elements (one integer array of size 2 and a float)?What I especially want to understand is why is the first case about **v1**'s initialization wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test1{
int list[2];
float rate;
}s1={{23,52},2.5},s2={21,19,3.6}; //Works fine

struct test2{
int list1;
int list2;
float rate;
}v1={{23,52},2.5},v2={21,19,3.6};  //Messes things up

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d,%d,%f\n",s1.list[1],s2.list[1],s2.rate);
    printf("%d,%d,%f\n",v1.list1,v1.list2,v1.rate);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a consequence of how the rules for initialisers are defined.  If the *current object* of the initialisation is a `struct`, `union` or array, then if the next initialiser begins with a `{` then the initialisers enclosed by that brace and its matching `}` are used to initialise the members of that object; otherwise, it just marches through the list of initialisers, taking as many as it needs.

So, in the first case `s1={{23,52},2.5}`, the current object starts out as `s1.list`.  This is an array, and the next initialiser is `{ 23, 52 }`, so that's used to initialise the array.  `s1.rate` is now the current object, and the next initialiser is `2.5`, so that works as expected.

In the second case `s2={21,19,3.6}`, the current object starts out as `s2.list`.  This is an array, but the next initialiser does *not* start out with `{` - so it takes as many values as it needs (in this case, two), and initialises the array with `21` and `19`.  `s2.rate` is now the current object, and the next initialiser is `2.5`, so again that works as expected.

In the third case `v1={{23,52},2.5}`, the current object starts out as `v1.list1`.  This is a scalar, and the corresponding initialiser is `{23, 52}`.  This violates a constraint of the language - *"The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces*" - so that's why you get a warning.  Formally the behaviour of your program is undefined, but it appears that your compiler just uses the first value contained in the initialiser and discards the excess ones.  The current object is now `v1.list2`, and the next initialiser is `2.5`, so the wrong value is used to initialise this member.  There is no initialiser for `v1.rate`; since `v1` has static storage duration, this member is initialiser to `0.0`.

In the forth case `v2={21,19,3.6}`, the current object starts out as `v1.list1`, and the next initialiser is `21` - this value is used to initialise the member.  After this the current object is `v1.list2` and the next initialiser is `19`; then `v1.rate` is the current object and the next initialiser is `3.6`.

For minimum confusion, you should always use a brace-enclosed initialiser for each `struct` or array subobject.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the variable `s2`, the compiler knows the size of the embedded array, so it can properly assign to it even without the bracers. you might however get a warning that suggests you to use bracers, and if you don't then I suggest you enable more compiler warnings (it's good to fix warnings, as they might indicate errors that might be valid C but invalid logic).

In the case `v1`, you can't use extra bracers because there is no compound data type (structure/union/array). The bracers `{}` can only be used to initialize compound data types.

Comment: It's not true that braces can only be used to initialise compound data types - braces containing a single value only are valid initialisers for scalar data types (eg. `int a = { 1 };` is valid, and in fact `{ 0 }` in particular is a universally valid initialiser).