# For "int demo[4][2]",why are all these same in magnitude: &demo[1],demo[1],demo+1,*(demo+1) ?What about type?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

Just when I had relaxed thinking I have a fair understanding of pointers in the context of arrays,I have fallen face down again over this following program.I had understood how for an array `arr`,`arr` and `&arr` are both same in magnitude,but different in type,but I fail to get a solid grip over the following program's output.I try to visualize it but succeed only partially.I would appreciate if you can give a rigorous and detailed explanation for this thing so that guys like me can be done with this confusion for good.

In the following program,I have used a "2D" array `demo[][2]`.I know that `demo[]` will be an `array of arrays` of size 2.I also know that `demo` used alone will be  of type `(*)[2]`.Still I am at a loss about the following :

**1)** Why is `&demo[1]` same as `demo[1]`?Isn't `demo[1]` supposed to be the address of the second array?What on earth is `&demo[1]` then and why is it same as address of the second array?

**2)** I know that the second `printf()` and fourth are same,as `demo[1]` is nothing else but `*(demo+1)`.But I've used it so to illustrate this point.How can it be equal to the third `printf()`,ie,how can **demo+1** be equal to ***(demo+1)**? `demo[1]` being the same as `*(demo+1)` is well-known,but how can `demo+1` be equal to `*(demo+1)`? **How can "something" be equal to the value at that "something"**?

**3)** And since it just proved I am not very smart,I should stop my guessing game and ask you for a conclusive answer about what are the **types** for the following :

**&demo[1]

demo[1]

demo+1**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int demo[4][2]= {{13,45},{83,34},{4,8},{234,934}};
    printf("%p\n",&demo[1]);
    printf("%p\n",demo[1]);  //Should have cast to (void*),but works still
    printf("%p\n",demo+1);
    printf("%p\n",*(demo+1));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0023FF28
0023FF28
0023FF28
0023FF28
```

Comment: **Finding** *demo[1] gives 83,an element of the 2nd array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`demo[1]` is the second member of the array `demo`, and is an array itself.  Just like any other array, when it's not the subject of the `&` or `sizeof` operator, it evaluates to a pointer to its first element - that is, `demo[1]` evaluates to the same thing as `&demo[1][0]`, the address of the first `int` in the array `demo[1]`.

`&demo[1]` is the address of the array `demo[1]`, and because the address of an array and the address of the first member of that array are necessarily the same location, `&demo[1]` is equal to `&demo[1][0]`, which is equal to a bare `demo[1]`.  This the key insight - the first element of an array is located at the same place in memory as the array itself, just like the first member of a `struct` is located at the same place in memory as the struct itself.  When you print `&demo[1]` and `demo[1]`, you're not printing a pointer to the array and an array; you're printing a pointer to the array and a pointer to the first member of that array.

`demo+1` is the address of the second member of `demo`. `*(demo+1)` is that member itself (it's the array `demo[1]`), but because that member is an array, it evaluates to a pointer to its first member.  As above, its first member is necessarily collocated with the array itself.  It's not that "something" is equal to the value at "something" - because when you use an array in an expression like that, it doesn't evaluate to the array itself.

- `&demo[1]` is a pointer to `demo[1]`, which is an array of 2 `int`.  So its type is `int (*)[2]`.
- `demo[1]` is an array of 2 `int`.  Its type is `int [2]`.  However, when used in an expression where it is not the subject of type `&` or `sizeof` operators, it will evaluate to a pointer to its first member, which is a value with type `int *`.
- `demo+1` is a pointer to `demo[1]`, and its type is `int (*)[2]`.

Comment: +1 really well worded answer. The second dimension and therefore addition *value* equivalencies of `demo+1`, `demo[1]`, and `&demo[1]`, notable the second of those, which would otherwise not be true in a 1D array, are really well laid out. I wish I could up-vote it again for the second bullet in the type-descriptions, notably the difference between `int (*)[2]` vs. `int *`, and why.

Comment: @WhozCraig My old pal,please take a look at this one too which **caf** has answered and leave your useful/helpful remarks there as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514806/for-a-structure-variable-why-is-the-initializer-21-19-3-6-same-as-21-19-3-6

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture caf's answer in that question is equally solid. I think I see a pattern forming there =P. I don't think I could answer it any better.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the array is laid out in memory:

```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |  13 |  45 |  83 |  34 |   4 |   8 | 234 | 934 |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   ^           ^           ^           ^
   |           |           |           |
demo[0]     demo[1]     demo[2]     demo[3]
```

Then also remember that naturally `demo` "points" to the first entry in the array. From this follows that `demo + 0` of course should point to the first entry as well, and another way of getting the address of an entry in the array is with the address-of operand `&` which would be `&demo[0]`. So `demo` is equal to `demo + 0` which is equal to `&demo[0]`.

Also remember that for your example, each entry in `demo` is another array, and arrays and pointers are pretty much interchangeable (as arrays decays to pointers). From this follows that `demo[0]` can be used as a pointer as well.

Now replace the `0` index above, with `1`, and you got the exact same thing as you are observing.

Comment: Can you also look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514806/for-a-structure-variable-why-is-the-initializer-21-19-3-6-same-as-21-19-3-6  **caf** has already blasted it with heavy artillery,but it would be still better if you too could take a few shots at it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        +-------+------+
                        |       |      |
                        |   13  |  45  |
                   101  |       |      | 105
                        +--------------+
                        |       |      |
                        |   83  |  34  |
                   109  |       |      | 113 
                        +--------------+
                        |       |      |
                        |   04  |  08  |
                   117  |       |      | 121 
                        +--------------+
                        |       |      |
                        |   234 | 934  |
                   125  |       |      | 129 
                        +--------------+
```

<sub>**Note:** Assuming `sizeof(int) = 4`</sub>

Assuming the 2D layout (its not that way in memory though, they are all in line)

`demo[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> row of the 2D array. which are themselves 1D arrays.
`demo[1]` is the `1`<sup>th</sup> row. [I mean the one with address `109`].

```
&demo[1]
```

is address of `demo[1]` and is the same as the base address of that row.Just like for 1D arrays. Array name gives the address of 1st location. Here 1D array name is `demo[1]`

```
demo[1]
```

since array names also give the base address of the array it is the same as `&demo[1]`

`demo+1`

`demo` is pointer and has value `101`. `demo` (i.e. `demo[0]`)is of type 1 row [shoddy description. What I mean is size of the row having two elements - `(*)[2]` ] So `demo+1` increments it to point to next row. Which is sane as `demo[1]`

```
*(demo+1)

demo+1 is the 1<sup>th</sup> row
```

and `*(demo+1)` means value at that location. This is itself an array, so it gives the address. since array names give addresses

Comment: I don't know about the rest of the answer,but I'm still looking at the nice ASCII art!!

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture We all need a little [help](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw) ;) :D I used [this](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)

Comment: How people do it?Manually?It must be taking lot of time and effort right?Or are there tools available?